# Inegration of wordpress in cakephp Application

Tags: cakephp

how i can extend the cake-app-authentication, so that the user is automatically logged in to the wordpress blog

Answer (score 0):

Basically it's not plug&play for sure.

First of all, your WP blog should be in the same domain as your CakeAPP (the best way will be if the blog is in a sub folder) i.e.:

http://yourdomain.com - cakephp application
http://yourdomain.com/blog - the blog

then you have to see what is stored in WP when a user is logged in and to fill the same array in your Cake App as well.

But I haven't done this, so it's just how I would do it.